# Convert a string to date (special format) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a column 'birthDate' which returns a string value of [Day of the Week], [Month] [Day], [Year] 
(e.g. Monday, December 30, 2013)

I am using `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(birthDate, '%m/%d/%Y')` but it returns a null value.

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(birthDate, '%W, %M %d, %Y')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing one format of your date ([Day of the Week], [Month] [Day], [Year]) but using another in `STR_TO_DATE` ([Month]/[Day]/[Year]). You need to provide `STR_TO_DATE` with the format your column is currently in:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(birthDate, '%W %m %d %Y')
```

If you want that result to be in a new format you can then use `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(birthDate, '%W %m %d %Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the record still returns a null value.

Comment: Can you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) so we can see it in action?